# Remote chunking with Spring Batch job distribution

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I have a technical issue running my Spring batch jobs.
The Job simply reading records from the DB (MongoDB) , making some calculations on the record (aggregations) and writing the record result to another table.
Reading A , Processing A , writing to record B
B is an aggregations of many records of A.
I want to use remote chunking to vertically scaling my system causing the processing part be scaled and quick.
The problem I face that I need to synchronize the A records so processing them will not conflict when writing the result to B.
If I distribute 10 A records to 4 slaves they will conflict when writing the aggregate result to B .

Any idea , how to add synchronizing policy when sending messages from the master to the slaves ?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to synchronize data like you're describing, I'd recommend not going with remote chunking and using partitioning instead.  This would allow you to partition by A and eliminate the synchronization issues you're facing.  It would also provide additional throughput as you'd be running one processor per slave (same as in remote chunking).

Comment: Thanks. Would you please recommend a link of particular example solving the problem.

Comment: Ok, I managed to run an example with local partitioning and its going well. One more question : How I can start the job again after partitioning X of A records. A table increasing all the time.

Comment: Just so I'm clear on your request, you want to know how to process only the new records in a table that is always getting new records?

Comment: Exactly. I want to process x new records and start again to the new incoming records.